# ¿Como defino automáticamente que cambie la fuente según el número de caracteres en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

¿Como defino automáticamente que cambie la fuente según el número de caracteres en javascript?, lo que sucede es que cuando se ejecuta la función solo me cambia el contenido que ya está visible, pero cuando se ingresa externamente otro no funciona o actualiza automaticamente, igual si cambio el texto de los textos.

```
  var textos = document.querySelectorAll(".texto");

    function revisartexto() {

        textos.forEach(function (texto) {
            var longitud = texto.innerHTML.length

            if (longitud < 150) {
                texto.classList.remove("textopequeno");
                texto.classList.add("textogrande");
            } else if (longitud > 150) {
                texto.classList.remove("textogrande");
                texto.classList.add("textopequeno");
            }

        })
    }
```

Comment: utiliza los eventos **keyup** o **keydown** según sea el caso.

Comment: Luis , por qué no usa los eventos `input` o `keydown` como menciono Cig ? ¿Se trata de un elemento de entrada, `input` , `textarea`?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el evento `DOMSubtreeModified` para detectar la modificación del contenido del elemento.

En este ejemplo cada vez que se hace click en el botón se rellenan los divs con un texto de longitud aleatoria.

En el evento `DOMSubtreeModified` de los divs se comprueba la longitud del texto contenido y se aplica un formato de texto u otro:

```js
var loremIpsum = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sagittis arcu maximus, facilisis ligula imperdiet, lobortis sem. Sed laoreet neque eu bibendum vestibulum. Nullam dictum vehicula nisi eget euismod. Etiam luctus velit orci, et maximus arcu finibus non. Curabitur ut fermentum lectus amet.'

var textos = document.querySelectorAll('.texto');

textos.forEach(function(texto){
  texto.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',
    function(){
      var longitud = this.innerText.length;
      texto.classList.remove(longitud < 150 ? 
        'textopequeno' : 'textogrande');
      texto.classList.add(longitud < 150 ? 
        'textogrande' : 'textopequeno');
    });
});

document.getElementById('rellenar').addEventListener('click', 
  function(){
    textos.forEach(function(texto){
      var longitud = Math.random() * 300;
      texto.innerText = loremIpsum.substr(0, longitud);
    });
  });
```

```css
.texto{
  border: solid 1px #999999;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.texto.textopequeno{
  font-size: 12px;
}

.texto.textogrande{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<button id="rellenar">Rellenar</button>
<div class="texto"></div>
<div class="texto"></div>
<div class="texto"></div>
<div class="texto"></div>
<div class="texto"></div>
<div class="texto"></div>
<div class="texto"></div>
<div class="texto"></div>
<div class="texto"></div>
```